# Evaluate the following definite integral.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I cannot for the life of me figure out what the answer to this homework problem is: [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXTXG.png)

This is the answer I keep getting: (21/2)-(234/3)+(609/4). But when I put this into a integral calculator to check my answer it gets: 889/12

My answer and the calculator's answer are not equivalent. I have put about 30 minutes into trying to figure this out. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Put your calculus, we can try find the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question seems to be trivial to answer. I give you a hint. Check whether you computed -(250/3+16/3) or -(250/3-16/3)?

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out due to this. Turns out I was not computing the negative number correctly.